# Displaying an order status form

Tags: javascript, php, html, curl

Below is code i used to call **Api** and display the "**Status**" results in web page.

[image]

my senior told me that code is completely mess and need to improve so that it should be easy to understand for others. but i am not getting how i can refactor below code ? is mixing php and html code is bad ? i really need to mix those html and php to get the results that i needed .please help me for this....

```
<p><button type= "button" class="call">Show Status</button></p>

    <table class="tbl-qa" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>    
               <th class="table-header"></th>     
               <th class="table-header">ORDERID</th>                                                      
               <th class="table-header">Status</th>                    
            </tr>
        </thead>

       <tbody id="table-body">
<?php
$tabindex = 1;

if (!empty($orderrecords))
    {
    foreach($orderrecords as $k => $v)
        { ?>

        <?php
        $hide = '';
        $data['username'] = 'admin';
        $data['password'] = 'admin123';     

        $url = 'https://plapi.ecomexpress.in/track_me/api/mawbd/?awb=awbnumber&order=' . $orderrecords[$k]["order_id"] . '&username=admin&password=admin123';
        $ch = curl_init();
        // some curl code
        $res = explode("\n", $output);
        if (!isset($res[13]))
            {
            $res[13] = null;
            }

        $status = $res[13];
?>

<tr class="table-row" id="table-row-<?php echo $orderrecords[$k]["id"]; ?>" tabindex="<?php echo $tabindex; ?>">

<td><input onclick="assignorderids('<?php echo $orderrecords[$k]["order_id"]; ?>')" type="checkbox" name="assigneeid" id="assigneeid-<?php echo $orderrecords[$k]["order_id"]; ?>" value="<?php echo $orderrecords[$k]["order_id"]; ?>"></td>

<td><?php echo $orderrecords[$k]["order_id"]; ?></td>             
<td><?php echo $status; ?></td>

</tr>


 <?php
 $tabindex++;
 }
    } ?>

    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Why don't you ask senior what is wrong?

Comment: @Toto he is not permanent employee working in our company , he usually visits some time in a week and check code of all beginner developers and tell us to improve, can you please help me for this.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can totally understand the frustration of your colleague that will need to maintain this code.

But would have been more constructive to tell that this code is considered a "mess" mainly because:

- Logic of fetching order status is mixed in the middle of table rendering;
- "Dirty" formatting: inconsistent indentation and trailing spaces;

The exact same thing could be better expressed like that:

```
<?php
function getOrderTrackingStatus($orderId) {
    $url = 'https://plapi.ecomexpress.in/track_me/api/mawbd/';
    $url.= "?awb=awbnumber&order=$orderId&username=admin&password=admin123";

    $ch = curl_init();
    // some curl code
    $res = explode("\n", $output);

    $status = isset($res[13]) ? $res[13] : null;
    return $status;
}
?>

<p>
    <button type="button" class="call">Show Status</button>
</p>

<table class="tbl-qa" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="table-header"></th>
            <th class="table-header">ORDERID</th>
            <th class="table-header">Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="table-body">
    <?php $tabindex = 1; ?>
    <?php foreach($orderrecords as $record): ?>

        <tr class="table-row"
            id="table-row-<?php echo $record['id']; ?>"
            tabindex="<?php echo $tabindex++; ?>">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox"
                       name="assigneeid"
                       id="assigneeid-<?php echo $record['order_id']; ?>"
                       value="<?php echo $record['order_id']; ?>"
                       onclick="assignorderids('<?php echo $record['order_id']; ?>')">
            </td>
            <td><?php echo $orderId; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo getOrderTrackingStatus($orderId); ?></td>
        </tr>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Ideally this `getOrderTrackingStatus` function would be moved somewhere else, instead of living inside the same file that handles data visualisation.

Hope it helps you, and depending on your project you should consider using a templating engine as a way to force yourself to move logic code away from the views.